# How to configure completions and suggestions in VS Code to be triggered by a key?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

**Context:** I appreciate the different completions and suggestions that VS Code can provide, from the language server, from GitHub Copilot, and from words in the document itself. However, I find it extremely irritating if things pop up while I type, and even more irritating if I accidentally accept a completion/suggestion when actually I wanted to go to the next tab stop. I'm therefore trying to configure VS Code in such a way that these popups and accidents don't happen – but I would still like to benefit from completion/suggestion when I want it, on pressing a key.

**Questions:** Unfortunately, in trying to figure out such a configuration I got quickly confused:

- In the settings, what is the difference between 'Tab Completion' (`editor.tabCompletion`) and 'Quick suggestions' (`editor.quickSuggestions`)?
- What is the difference between 'Trigger Inline Suggestion' (`editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger`, no keybinding) and 'Trigger Suggest' (`editor.action.triggerSuggest`, bound to both Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+I)?
- There doesn't seem to be an editor action 'Trigger Completion'?

Comment: your title asks one thing, and then your body asks two different things. see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: what do you mean by "trigger completion"? Do you mean to accept a suggestion? Or to trigger the suggestions widget for later selecting something to accept?

Comment: It would help if you clarified more about what you don't understand about the descriptions of the settings you listed. They seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: @starball The first paragraph provides context, the second is the actual question and does correspond to the title.